# How to Switch From CentOS 8 to CentOS Stream

Tags: centos, upgrade

Is there any way to do a sort of in-place upgrade to CentOS Stream? I'm currently running CentOS 8 and for various reasons would like to switch over to the new Stream version. Is it possible to do without having to reinstall the OS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: Please check out [Anthony Geoghegan's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/634133/98522) for the latest recommendations.

This should work as CentOS Stream is just additional repositories on top of CentOS 8 [as mentioned on (unofficial) centosfaq.org](https://centosfaq.org/centos/moving-from-centos-8-to-stream-and-possibly-back-again/).

I did this on my development machine:

```
$ dnf history centos-release-stream
ID     | Command line             | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   156 | update --allowerasing    | 2020-03-27 14:10 | E, I, U        |  127  <
   154 | install -y centos-releas | 2020-03-27 14:04 | Install        |    1 >
```

Which resulted in the following enabled repositories

```
$ dnf repolist enabled | grep CentOS
AppStream                 CentOS-8 - AppStream
BaseOS                    CentOS-8 - Base
PowerTools                CentOS-8 - PowerTools
Stream-AppStream          CentOS-Stream - AppStream
Stream-BaseOS             CentOS-Stream - Base
Stream-extras             CentOS-Stream - Extras
centosplus                CentOS-8 - Plus
extras                    CentOS-8 - Extras
fasttrack                 CentOS-8 - fasttrack
```

I needed to get rid of some manually compiled packages (`--allowerasing`) though. I would not do this on a production server or without a functioning backup.

Comment: Just to clarify: To switch from a "normal" CentOS 8 installation to Stream, you have to `dnf install centos-release-stream` followed by a `dnf update`. Then your `/etc/redhat-release` will read: `CentOS Stream release 8`.

Answer (score 8):

After, it was announced that CentOS 8 would no longer be supported (end-of-life on 31 December 2021), upgrading to CentOS Stream became the officially recommended path to continue to receive software updates (RPMs).

Here are the notes I made while following the instructions for [Converting from CentOS Linux to CentOS Stream](https://www.centos.org/centos-stream/):

**1. Install the CentOS-Stream release files.**

```
dnf install centos-release-stream
```

This package installs the following files:

```
/etc/dnf/vars/stream
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Stream-AppStream.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Stream-Base.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Stream-Debuginfo.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Stream-Extras.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Stream-Media.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Stream-PowerTools.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Stream-Sources.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Stream-Vault.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Stream-centosplus.repo
```

**2. Replace the `centos-linux` repositories with `centos-stream` repositories:**

```
dnf swap centos-{linux,stream}-repos
```

The above utilises Bash’s *brace expansion* to run this command:

```
dnf swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos
```

which replaces the following packages:

```
centos-release-stream
centos-release
centos-repos
```

with

```
centos-stream-repos
centos-stream-release
```

**3. Update all packages to match the latest version available from all enabled repositories**

```
sudo dnf distro-sync
```

For me, this installed a large number of packages, removed older kernel packages and downgraded the following packages:

```
httpd-2.4.37-30.module_el8.3.0+462+ba287492.0.1.x86_64
httpd-filesystem-2.4.37-30.module_el8.3.0+462+ba287492.0.1.noarch
httpd-tools-2.4.37-30.module_el8.3.0+462+ba287492.0.1.x86_64
```

However, it failed while attempting to upgrade the `filesystem` package and further attempts to run `dnf update` failed due to:

> Error unpacking rpm package filesystem-3.8-4.el8.x86_64

This was because I had a filesystem mounted on `/mnt`.  Unmounting this allowed the `filesystem` package to be upgraded and allowed the operation to complete successfully:

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Stream release 8
```

Note: I’ve only converted my own workstation to CentOS Stream. I have yet to replicate this procedure on a production server. :)

Comment: Your note about the `filesystem` package is interesting, because I have a few LXC containers with the same issue, but haven't been bothered to figure out why. Thanks for all the info!

Answer (score 1):

If you reach Centos 8 end of life and can't update using

> dnf install centos-release-stream

Because Centos 8 repos are gone, you can search for the package centos-release-stream on the net download it to your Centos 8 and use

> dnf install centos-release-stream-8.1-1.1911.0.7.el8.x86_64.rpm

as a local file, then continue the procedure mention on this post. It works, for me.

Comment: Where can I get that file?

Answer (score -1):

Not that I know of. Backup your system and boot a Stream image of your choice to install it. Make sure you look at the [release notes](https://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOSStream).