# How to switch to Centos 8 from CentOS Stream

Tags: centos

Asking the *reverse* of this question: [How to Switch **From CentOS 8** to CentOS Stream](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552873/how-to-switch-from-centos-8-to-centos-stream)

I am presuming it is as straight forward removing the extra packages as per René's answer (in linked question). Namely the ones labelled `CentOS-Stream`:

```
$ dnf repolist enabled | grep CentOS
AppStream                 CentOS-8 - AppStream
BaseOS                    CentOS-8 - Base
PowerTools                CentOS-8 - PowerTools
Stream-AppStream          CentOS-Stream - AppStream    #
Stream-BaseOS             CentOS-Stream - Base         #
Stream-extras             CentOS-Stream - Extras       #
centosplus                CentOS-8 - Plus
extras                    CentOS-8 - Extras
fasttrack                 CentOS-8 - fasttrack
```

But has anyone actually done this, or can confirm my assumption from their larger *nix experience?

-- edit --

I went to actually investigate this today, and found that I don't have the CentOS 8 repos listed above... So I guess Stream isn't an "add on" as such. I suppose that makes sense.

```
appstream          CentOS Stream 8 - AppStream
baseos             CentOS Stream 8 - BaseOS
epel               Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
epel-modular       Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64
extras             CentOS Stream 8 - Extras
nginx              nginx repo
```

So, there goes the "that should be easy enough" idea. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I haven't done it, so I can't help, but in case you haven't heard: the standard CentOS is being discontinued shortly, and CentOS Stream will be the only CentOS left. Of course there can still be valid reasons for making the move you plan to make, but in the long run, it will likely become a dead end.

Comment: Hey Kevin, Thanks for the thought. I had heard, and that's why I'm moving to v8. I saw Stream being lanuched, and thought it sounded good - as I've had good experiences with Solus - but I didn't realise it had moved positions to be upstream from RHEL. Now I'm waiting for Rocky to release.

Comment: Besides Rocky, there are a number of other distros you may want to look at. I'm planning to look at Springdale, since it comes from the same environment we are in (academic and HPC). There also is Oracle Linux, although it may have its own corporate problems.

Comment: TBH, I move between flavours reasonably well. I just downloaded Garuda to play with Arch for the first time (by the by). But I've always liked the CentOS/RHEL servers. They've always been "home" if you know what I mean. It does kinda bug me that they're so far behind the current kernel though.

Comment: Springdale is another RHEL clone, similar to CentOS.

Comment: Yes, forked from Scientific Linux, isn't it? I had thought about that, but it's heritage made me think it might have some crazy science overhead involved that I would need to remove / turn off. Have you used it? I'm primarily in Web Dev. (Also hoping CloudLinux's free community edition comes out soon too. This particular application is development server)

Comment: this might help :<https://forums.rockylinux.org/t/centos-8-centos-stream-rocky-linux/2343/3>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears that all you need to do is:

1. Get the CentOS-*.repo files (without Stream in the name) from an other CentOS 8 box. (I had to use a new VM)
2. Copy & Paste / `scp` to the box in question
3. Disable all the CentOS-Stream-*.repo files in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`
4. Run `dnf distro-sync` which will downgrade some things (many, many things)
5. Reboot

This held the answer: https://centosfaq.org/centos/moving-from-centos-8-to-stream-and-possibly-back-again/

That link's "switch back command" also has an instruction to `dnf remove centos-release-stream`, and a removal of the now defunct CentOS-Stream-*.repo files. Which I may do, presuming that I have not killed the box in question.

I will update this answer once the fate of said box is known.

-- edit: Post above operations --

Said box now doesn't appear to fully boot into Gnome. And root cannot login via SSH. So that's fun. I can still use Webmin, which is good. And while I can reset the root password there, it makes no difference to the denying of root's login.

The issue was the PAM config files were gone. The Solution for no-login was to copy all the content of the *files* in /etc/authselect (not the ones in /etc/authselect/custom) to the box in question. (Clearly, you can only do this if you have access to the machines file system. But as I said, I had Webmin running, so that worked for me)

Hooray!

Now, as to the `dnf remove centos-release-stream`, it returns:

```
Repository extras is listed more than once in the configuration
Error: 
Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: setup
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

I'm not convinced I need to care about that though. With the repo's disabled, I can't foresee an issue arising here. (But it would be nice to remove it for completions sake.)

-- edit: Review --

I have established one reason to move/remove the *.repo files - `yum` / `dnf` don't like it when these files have repo= the same in two files. I simply moved the CentOS-Stream* files into a new subdirectory and `chmod`'d that directory as 000 so it didn't see them. All seems to work nicely now :)

Answer (score 3):

So, I found the above answer, and it superceded my question and was excellent but I have found from the above a simpler, and more back-reversible way to do this.

1. mv /etc/yum.repos.d to /etc/yum_stream.repos.d
   This makes a copy of the state of the repos files on the date you're switching back, and also makes them not "seen" by yum/dnf
2. cp -ax /etc/authselect ~/AuthSelect
3. make a copy of the /etc/yum.repos.d from a VM that is correct ( including epel, and any other repos you had before and still want).
4. dnf distro-sync
5. cp -ax ~/AuthSelect /etc/authselect

And voila, seems to work beautifully.  Now if you want to switch on a regular basis, it's easy, and you've got "what you had" ready to switch back.

BTW, for anyone who likes the NVIDIA drivers, or (heaven forbid) wants to install a CUDA development system, DON'T go to stream.  Didn't realize this, but the NVIDIA proprietary drivers just aren't available.

I'm looking at Rocky and now just saw Springdale, which looks nice. I have also in the past had a RHEL license, but now I'm torn because I don't want to reward what certainly feels like bad behaviour by the current RH ownership.  But I do understand wanting folks to pony up for a rock stable, secure  distro.  Not sure what I'm doing now...

Comment: Nice :) Good solution. As well as Rocky and Springdale, there's Alma Linux too (almalinux.org) from CloudLinux.

Comment: Thanks much!  I will check out the Alma Linux.  Your solution was a lifesaver, and all I did was a bit of a polish of it.  I liked Scientific linux, but they let things stop at 8, since CENTOS was a good solution.  If they come back, that's probably exactly where I'll go, but I'm not sure that's going to happen.

Comment: Also, on the Scientific linux, I can't comment on your post, but I have that (RHEL7 vintage) in a VM, and it works great.  There isn't any real overhead, but some of the packages that numerical folks use are used to.  I'd already tuned my Centos system at that time, so there was no net benefit, and though I liked the idea at that time, it just didn't make sense.  I just rebooted the 7.2 version, and we'll see if it can update itself.  It's been a while.  There will be much updating occuring for a while.  I'm guessing it's a lot like the Princeton/Institute for advanced study version?

Comment: seems like Scientific Linux may not be the right path? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Linux & https://listserv.fnal.gov/scripts/wa.exe?A2=SCIENTIFIC-LINUX-ANNOUNCE;11d6001.1904 both state they're moving to CentOS 8 actual for their uses. But I believe it was aimed at scientific number crunching.

Comment: Scientific Linux issued an [_update_](https://linux.web.cern.ch/#update-on-centos-linux-strategy)  to that on May 5 2021  which (to my reading)  was that Stream was not an acceptable alternative, and they were evaluating what to do. For me Springdale linux looks good, as does Rocky.  I'm in the Springdale or Scientific Linux type of world, as I am a massager of digits.  Rocky's got a "beta" version out, which looks quite good to me.  The Springdale also seems to work nicely.  (Both in VM's).  For the time being, having my Centos 8 working till the successor becomes clear is a real boon!