# How to Switch From CentOS 8 to CentOS Stream after repos no longer available

Tags: centos

After the repo urls are gone the [old answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552873/how-to-switch-from-centos-8-to-centos-stream) don't work anymore:

```
$ sudo dnf install centos-release-stream
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C.UTF-8
CentOS-8 - Base                                                                                            38 kB/s | 282  B     00:00    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'BaseOS':
  - Status code: 404 for http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 79.143.183.106)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'BaseOS': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

How can I switch now?

---

Edit:

The [explanation from the official page](https://www.centos.org/centos-stream/), don't seem to work either:

```
dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos
dnf distro-sync

CentOS-8 - Base                                                                                            39 kB/s | 282  B     00:00    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'BaseOS':
  - Status code: 404 for http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 79.143.183.106)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'BaseOS': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

Comment: you might want to switch mirrors.

Comment: None of the mirrors have the Centos 8 content anymore.

Comment: I suggest checking for typos, because if `—disablerepo=‘*’` is set, you wouldn’t have BaseOS being checked.

Comment: @jsbillings it was not typos, but somehow switching required the BaseOS repo to be available

Comment: I’m glad you resolved it, but the instructions work as described.  The old CentOS 8 “extras” repo is still around and has the centos-stream-repos package.  I can see in the output you included that you didn’t exclude BaseOS, there is no way that output would appear if you ran the command correctly.

Comment: Consider installing AlmaLinux or Rocky LInux if you want to avoid the whole stream thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS 8 repos are still available in [Vault](https://vault.centos.org/) so you can use the URLs below in your `.repo` files.

You'll need `BaseOS` and `Extras` so edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Linux-BaseOS.repo` and `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Linux-Extras.repo` and comment out the `mirrorlist=` line, uncomment  the `baseurl=` line and replace it with

```
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/BaseOS/$basearch/os/
```

for the `BaseOS` repo and

```
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/extras/$basearch/os/
```

for the `Extras` repo. Now the `dnf swap` command should work

```
dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo baseos,extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos
```

Comment: Thank you! I wonder why i needed the old repos to switch away from them.

Comment: Both `centos-linux-repos` and `centos-stream-repos` are packages so you need to download the `centos-stream-repos` package (which actually contains the `/etc/yum.repos.d` repo files for CentOS Stream) from somewhere before you can start using the new repos (`dnf swap` just uninstallas `centos-linux-repos` and installs `centos-stream-repos` in one step).

Comment: Makes sense, thanks again!

Comment: @Vojtech Trefny: you don’t actually need to manually download the repo packages.  The “extras” repo is still available for CentOS 8: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/extras/x86_64/os/Packages/

Comment: @jsbillings I don't know why but I did not have the extras repo set up, I just skipped that step and it works now.

Comment: @jsbillings The extras repo didn't work for me with the default mirrorlist and I also needed baseos for `centos-gpg-keys` which the `dnf swap` also wanted to install. I tested this with a vagrant CentOS 8 image because I didn't have any CentOS 8 installation so it might be different with a fully upgraded CentOS 8.

Answer (score 2):

May 2022:
The following worked for me moving from CentOS 8 to CentOS Stream 8:

```
# sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
# sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g'  /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
# dnf install centos-release-stream -y --allowerasing
# dnf swap centos-{linux,stream}-repos
# dnf distro-sync --best --allowerasing
# reboot
```